# Как получить доступ к ключ словам страницы через расширение Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Как получить доступ к ключ словам страницы через расширение Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

через

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.querySelectorAll(\'meta[name="keywords"]\')'
    }, (results) => {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

имея permission "activeTab".